# How to install hadoop reusable on a local network?

Tags: installation, best-practices, hadoop

For a multi-node image cluster on an institute, we have sevaral laptops and machines and we want to create a hadoop cluster with hbase on the top for indexing the data/images.

I have tried some VMare and docker solutions, but the most tutorials are deprecated and very complicated. The sandboxes are not recommended for a productional usage.

I have now, 3 macbook pros with 16gb ram, 2 win pcs with 8gb ram.

I want to take a macbook as a masternode and the other machines as slaves / datanodes.

What's the best way for us to end up with a cluster where we can read and write very large image files? The cluster will set up in a local network.

Thanks in advice.